# xcode10にてエラー

Tags: swift4

アプリ開発の超初心者ですが、アプリ開発入門書にて教本通りに作業を進めておりますが、何度やり直しても同じエラーが出てシュミレーターを実行できません。
エラーについて色々検索致しましたがたどり着けず困っています。
どうぞご教授お願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: エラーになるコード、エラーメッセージなどは可能な限りテキストとして質問本文中にご記載ください。ご自身の質問は「編集」から編集することが可能です。ビルド時のエラーメッセージについては、Xcode左部のNavigationエリアからReport Navigator(吹き出しの中身が＝のアイコン)を選んで辿っていくとコピペ可能な形で表示することができます。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージを見る限りだと、クラスの閉じかっこ(})が足りないだけのようです。
switchブロックのインデントが一段ずれていて気付いていないだけではないでしょうか。

一度OOPerさんがご指摘されているとおり、ソースをテキストとして提示していただけるとはっきりすると思います。

Comment: アドバイス通り色々見直してみましたら、最後の } が抜けており無事解決し実機に転送できました。